# 403 error in production by the update function of my laravel resource controller

Tags: laravel, controller, authorization, policy

Good morning
I hope you're doing well. I need your help.

I am currently working on a project on which I have an admin part where I have to manage the creation of blog articles. So I created a resource route for that.

Locally, everything works, no problem.
As soon as I go online and try to update an article, I get a 403 error in the console and I am redirected to this route administrator/posts/1

Creating my route

```
Route::middleware('auth', 'verified', 'role:admin')->prefix('administrator')->group(function () {
  Route::resource('posts', AdminPostController::class)->names([
        'index' => 'admin.posts.index',
        'create' => 'admin.posts.create',
        'store' => 'admin.posts.store',
        'show' => 'admin.posts.show',
        'edit' => 'admin.posts.edit',
        'update' => 'admin.posts.update',
        'destroy' => 'admin.posts.destroy',
    ]);
}
```

Here is the content of my middleware role

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string $role): Response
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        if ($user && $user->role === $role) return $next($request);
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        abort(403);
    }
```

Which I saved in my kernel

```
'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureUserHasRole::class,
```

Here is the content of my update() function. I know it's not perfect and I need to narrow it down further

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'titre' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($post),
            ],
            'myContent' => 'required|string',
            'etiquettes' => ['array'],
            'categorie' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'image' => 'image|max:1024',
        ]);

    }
```

Of course in my controller constructor I call authorizeResource()

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Post::class, 'post');
    }
```

Here is the content of my PostPolicy

```
<?php

class PostPolicy
{

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post): bool
    {
        return $user->role === "admin" && $user->id === $post->user_id; //Il faut être auteur d'un post pour le modifier
    }

}
```

And finally The article update form.

```
                    <form method="POST" id="form" action="{{ route('admin.posts.update', ['post' => $post->id]) }}"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea id="contenu" class="form-control @error('myContent') is-invalid @enderror" name="contenu" required>{{ $post->content }}</textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="myContent" id="myContent" value="">
                                @error('myContent')
                                    <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitformBtn">Enregistrer</button>
                    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Configuration de tinymce
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea#contenu',
                plugins: [
                    "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", "fullscreen",
                    "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media",
                    "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks", "accordion"
                ],
                height: 400,
                toolbar: "link image accordion | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough | align | bullist numlist | forecolor | preview",
                menubar: false,
            });
            // Configuration de select2
            $('.etiquettes').select2({
                placeholder: 'Selectionner ou ajouter des etiquettes',
                selectionCssClass: 'dropdownEtiquettes',
                tags: true,
                tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
            });
            // Gestion de la soumession du formulaire
            $('#submitformBtn').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var myContent = tinymce.get("contenu").getContent({
                    format: 'html'
                });
                document.getElementById('myContent').value = myContent;
                document.getElementById("form").submit();
            });

        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

I've been constantly looking for the cause of the problem for the past few days and can't find anything. I thought there was definitely something an outside eye would see. I would be delighted to have your opinion on this 403 in production but not locally.

At the beginning, I did not set up the policies. I was just content with my controller and middleware. It was when the error occurred that I set up the policies. In addition in my public folder, I had an admin folder which I finally renamed because it could be the cause but all my temptations were unsuccessful. I must add that updating other models works

Comment: Code examples provided here should be minimal. Please remove some unnecessary parts, which will also help you with debugging.

Comment: @Destroy666 Thank you for your reply. I cleaned up the code a bit